# Mark complex object as readonly in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an Angular service singleton that I use as a Vault to centralize information about some features my App had. There I have an object that is the one source of true of them.

It is something like

```
enum FeatureEnum {
  SomeFeature = 'SomeFeature',
  SomeOtherFeature = 'SomeOtherFeature'
}


class MyService {
  public featureObjects: Record<FeatureEnum, SomeComplexObjectType> = {
     [FeatureEnum.SomeFeature]: '',// some complex object,
     [FeatureEnum.SomeOtherFeature]: '',// some complex object
   }

  get AsArray()...

  get AsMap()...

  get OtherThings()...
}
```

I want to create some kind of Mapped type that make everything that comes from `featureObjects` from typescript point of view (That is, I do not really care if it is writable on run time. Although It is nice to have).

Using a type like `Readonly<MyService>` just make the top members readonly. I would like to have some kind of "Recursive" Readonly. Is that possible?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAYsCGAXMAnYBRc0DeBYAUFFAMoD2EwcSqwUAvFAORkVXJqMA0BRLwA8ogAWwFGxr0mfQSLEJ2wRgQC+BAgEsQiUQDN4AY1oARJPCh5CUbQA9EALigBnRCk0BzbpcflgAOUgARqIOWEEoKhpauga0AELwjsAAwqQgOupu5jxQIPAUDs6uIB7ZACamDiaI8BH4kdooeoZQ8YniaFmWiOoUxNUQAA4hgaKeRPqp6W4OrcmTGbUE+gA2CY5QALIAnsSiAG7qzRZEA2ABy4dOPsLukozeFDfFjADc2afnlzryNPwBAFbAfSIRwOABKQNIKFKAB52hgsJwWglKD80AA+STHIhQADa8MwkAAdHx4QBdBzYnFWHrAPp5IZQACMAAY2WNqVAJmkMpTspycnlgA5mD54Vx+ZzytU+ZYBUQbPYmA9aAAVYC2CVy+Uq-wQMIOVmS6mqbVEU3y43KTgAehtVwoXPIA2WGqgpABQMQHJx+LRCOJ0mEonJsoF3V6-UZAFY2SyfTjuVMw-LcvkpGL-Vr5VBpfAUznFSKVVB1ZqEwLdSMUIaWcacRbOY3OVbbfaSxNBq7rO7PcDsqbFvhuc4HcAAJIgQHA9SpSQgYAAd02O32h2AAAoAJRQBJQCHwUqpZZbGHbXYoA6GdFvOr4FWT6fdVJElVPTIMRiqoTqdaq1xuG4oi7iApZbAMwCOPorgDIgUCiCgUKvAQD5Tl6s4gES3zUGgfxPo4JKZjhwBEhGdJRpIrJsi8UB2lAARgHB36-lAi5QgA1us8AgKUUDqHBjhCKQYDLKUICMIgRJSTRaj3j4j7oS+2EKHhXoEaS-pEkmGREmmtCfsxXHLN4rEcesDECUJIm8SApCIAAhK8UAofJaEzkp-qqcC6lEQoWnzG4RJ5qRGpwQZP5GSZbEoJx9GMU4VmiTkdmOTRQA)

Comment: So maybe you want `type DeepReadonly<T> = T extends Function ? T : T extends object ? { readonly [K in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[K]> } : T;` but I'd like to see a [mcve] in the question before I can say for certain.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi @jcalz, I have updated my playground link (and moved to the bottom). Thanks!

Comment: The `DeepReadonly` solution by @jcalz sounds reasonable. A variant of this is also available as npm package: [utility-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utility-types#deepreadonlyt) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible you want a recursive mapped conditional type like this:

```
type DeepReadonly<T> = T extends Function ? T :
  T extends object ? { readonly [K in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[K]> } :
  T;
```

This should leave `T` alone if it's a primitive type or a function; otherwise it recursively walks down through the properties making them `readonly` ones.  I special-cased function types because mapping over function types tends to produce the empty type `{}` (call signatures are not preserved in mapped types), and you'd presumably like to be able to call methods in your classes.  If that's not important, you can remove that clause.

Anyway, using the `MyService` class from your example code (and adding a `someMethod()` method to show that methods still work):

```
const someInjection = new MyService() as DeepReadonly<MyService>;

someInjection.something = ''; // error, readonly
someInjection.featureObjects.SomeFeature.timeStamp = 1000; // error, readonly
someInjection.featureObjects.SomeFeature.config.name = ''; // error, readonly
someInjection.featureObjects.SomeFeature.config.data.text = ''; // error, readonly
someInjection.someMethod(); // okay
```

Looks good.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAYsCGAXMAnYBRc0DeBYAUFFAMoD2EwcSqwUAvFAORkVXJqMA0BRLwA8ogAWwFGxr0mfQSLEJ2wRgQC+BAgEsQiUQDN4AY1oARJPCh5CUbQA9EALigBnRCk0BzbpcflgAOUgARqIOWEEoKhpauga0AELwjsAAwqQgOupu5jxQIPAUDs6uIB7ZACamDiaI8BH4kdooeoZQ8YniaFmWiOoUxNUQAA4hgaKeRPqp6W4OrcmTGbUE+gA2CY5QALIAnsSiAG7qzRZEA2ABy4dOPsLukozeFDfFjADc2afnlzryNPwBAFbAfSIRwOABKQNIKFKAB52hgsJwWglKD80AA+STHIhQADa8MwkAAdHx4QBdBzYnFWHrAPp5IZQACMAAY2WNqVAJmkMpTspycnlgA5mD54Vx+ZzytU+ZYBUQbPYmA9aAAVYC2CVy+Uq-wQMIOVmS6mqbVEU2S5ScAD01quFC55AGyw1UFIAKBiA5RHxaIRxOkwlE5NlAu6vX6jIArGyWd6cdypqH5bl8lIxX6tfKoNL4Mns4qRSqoOrNfGBbqRihDSzjTjTQKLdqrbb7bQJoMXdY3R7gdkG22NsBhKRSgAKACU5igTabiC2A2MwGAAwh8FKqWWWxhqsxDFVUA12hApXWMDAIGB6lSUAA-CWoHZsgej6BTz3AcC79O0OvN1s8QAaSgTQoAAa2ALZSB0EsKSgIxl1XBANxALcd1xQCyUxZRH2fN46nwblnDbABJEBP26G8GBAYAAHdNh2fZDmAScoASeDELXFC0O2XYUAOQx0XwggVTIijrxAIkVSeTIGEYV4oFbUQUChJFf24rYRJ8MTPQkolvmoNA-goxwSQzQzgCJcM6UjSRWTZF5FLtZTVKgdT-y0igdKvVJ9L9YzPVM0k-SJRMMiJVNaDkhSlJQFSUDU5CPPwUTyN03yDIUALgSC8yFFC+Y3CJXMrKPO4YucuLXPc1DNJS7S0p8ySVSHEdxwnRzW1IMD4C2IA)