type-challenges：Why this answer couldn't pass all cases?
Recently I am interested in type challenges.Today I plan to solve 9.Deep Readonly problem.
Problem
My answer is just like this.
type DeepReadonly<T> = {
  readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Object ? DeepReadonly<T[K]> : T[K];
}

type-challenges' link
Why this answer couldn't pass all cases?Who could give an right answer?

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

@Phil
That Comment is a worth a Million
But I guess OP is learning TS and just couldn't see why his Solution didn't pass all the Cases. I guess he's seeking for clarity as opposed to fixing Issues on a Project. The one thing I noticed was that the Link doesn't go directly to the Issue he was solving. It rather opens the entire Page which contains lots of Tests and you just have to do some extra work to dig it out.... The precise Link would have been: https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/00009-medium-deep-readonly/README.md

Yeah,this is just my problem.

@风雪心
You may wanna take a look at this link  =>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59698798/mark-complex-object-as-readonly-in-typescript
type DeepReadonly<T> = T extends Function ? T :
T extends object ? { readonly [K in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[K]> } :
T;

Please include all relevant code as plaintext in the question itself. Links to code are not sufficient to be a [mre]. Until the code is included here as plaintext, the question risks being closed as needing debugging details.

So Need I to show the problem in the form of plaintext?

Yes, the whole problem should be here as plaintext. Please [edit] to do that. We cannot ask people to go to another web site to see the question code.

functions also extend the object type, so checking against the object type is too broad and would be running any methods through DeepNested.  So if we handle the function case first we can return it's type before we check for an object type.
type DeepReadonly<T> = {
  readonly [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends Function
    ? T[Key]
    : T[Key] extends object
    ? DeepReadonly<T[Key]>
    : T[Key];
};


Yes,the Function should be considered specially.
